# Sql query to get result in asc order but 0 values should be last after all data

Tags: sql

I want all student list which have `> 0` marks in asc order and then all 0 marks student.
I made a query for this, but this not give correct response:

```
(SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE marks>0)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE marks=0)
```

after union this merge the data.

Kindly suggest me, what should I do for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM tbl_student ORDER BY CASE WHEN marks = 0 THEN 9999 ELSE marks END ASC`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
tbl_student ORDER BY
CASE WHEN marks = 0
THEN 9999 ELSE marks
END
```

Instead of 9999 you can give your maximum number

Comment: lol.its just my answer. i dint see that you have posted. after that ly came to know

Answer (score -1):

Try ORDER BY a CASE statement if your SQL flavour supports that, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_student ORDER BY CASE WHEN marks>0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: You're right, it just sorts the 0 and non-0 marks...  Based on the OP's SQL statements

Comment: Right, I interpreted the request as asking to sort the mark values as well: "I want all student list which have > 0 marks in asc"

Comment: I could just add ",marks" to the end of the statement and do the same in a slightly different manor than your answer :)

Comment: Of course - I was not challenging your ability - just clarifying the interpretation of the question.

Comment: Haha didn't mean to imply any of that if I did